# IValidatableObject.Validate() vs Validator.TryValidateObject()

Tags: c#, validation

Most examples I've seen for using IValidatableObject's use the Validator to validate an object like this:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateMyModel(IValidatableObject model){
     var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
     Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model), validationResults);

     return validationResults;
}
```

But I've also seen the IValidatableObject.Validate() method used like this:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateMyModel(IValidatableObject model){
     return model.Validate(new ValidationContext(model));
}
```

Is there any functional difference between the two approaches or any considerations that should be made before choosing which approach to use to validate an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Validator.TryValidateObject` will check the `RequiredAttribute` of the properties, any `ValidationAttribute` attached to the type and the `Validate` method of the `IValidatableObject`.

`model.Validate` will not check any attribute.